# PHP - using include, can i execute on a different div in the page?

Tags: php, html

I have a small problem, and I'll try to break it down into a smaller one so I can explain it properly.

I'm working on a web application and I have a couple of divs, such as this:

```
<div class="1">
//search bar
</div>

<div class="2">
include_once 'actioncontroller.php';
</div>

<div class="3">

</div>
```

In the actioncontroller.php I'm having an action controller which decides what action to take depending on what's pressed on the page. I've put it in the second div because ultimately that's where I want to print everything.

My question is, is there any way that I can use the code from the second div in the first one, without it printing it there? Basically I want the search bar from div one to do/print the same thing as the one in div 2 does, but I know(think) that PHP can't see code above the include_once, and if I include the actioncontroller.php in the first div it will print it there, instead of printing it in the second one, as I want.

Hope I was clear enough, it's not a problem of coding, it's just a matter of how can I read the script in the first div and then run it in the second one...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have access to actioncontroller.php?

Comment: Can't you just put the content that you want to print in a variable? Another options would be to write a global function that you call in each div.

Comment: Have you considered throwing some javascript in the mix? That way you could use the search bar, call a javascript function when it's used and output the result of a php script in the second div via ajax.

Comment: The question is not clear. Please show more code and explain exactly what do you need.

Comment: @Timmy That's like trying to fix a burned out light-bulb by breaking into the building next door, setting up an elaborate series of mirrors, and phoning the neighbor whenever you need them to turn their lights back on.

Comment: @Darien Lmao, that bad eh? I definitely see what you mean, though - just trying not to laugh my neighbours to consciousness!

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is there any way that I can use the code from the second div in the first one, without it printing it there?

Yes, but the best solution is to change the code you've already written. In the long-term, it is vitally important that you minimize your "procedural" PHP code, so that nothing **ever** happens simply by `include`/`require`-ing a file.

Trust me on this, it works for toy project, but it always leads to insanity and pain in the end. For example, **don't** put this in a file:

```
<?php    
echo("Header section");
```

This is bad because you have *no choice* about *when* it prints. This is a step up:

```
<?php
function WriteHeader(){
    echo("Header section");
}
```

Even better would be to use classes an autoloading, but that's probably more than you need to hear right now. With that kind of approach, your main page would look more like:

```
<?php
// This next line simply makes the class ActionController *available*, 
// it does NOT cause new things to happen on its own
include_once("actioncontroller.php");

?>
<div class="1">
    <?= ActionController::MakeSomeHTML(); ?>
</div>

<div class="2">
    <?= ActionController::MakeSomeHTML(); ?>
</div>

<div class="3">

</div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit new to stackoverflow so I don't really know how much code to put. I'm using some sort of a MVC pattern a bit modified for my needs. In this case, I have 2 classes, one which is a controller and another one which is the model which would do the searching bit. I have instances of those classes, but I still don't get how to make the form (the search bar) from div 1 to print in the second div. If for example I'm running the instance of the controller in div 2 that has an isset for when the search bar s button was pressed, would that work better?

Answer (score 0):

This code takes the output of actioncontroller.php and saves it into a variable, which can be `echo`'d multiple times.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once 'actioncontroller.php';
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>

<div class="1">
    <?php echo $output; ?>
</div>

<div class="2">
    <?php echo $output; ?>
</div>
```